# Jump phenomena for primary resonance of the Duffing equation

Tags: plotting

In this equation I will write omega (`Ω`) instead of amplitude (`a`).

```
ϵ = 0.1;
f = 0.01;
μ = 0.1;
Ω = 1 + ϵ (3/8 a^2 + Sqrt[f^2/(4 a^2) - μ^2])
```

I want to get this equation's graphics. Horizontal axis will be Ω and veritical axis will be `a`.

Comment: I researched a lot. I could not find.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of *Mathematica*'s [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseFunction.html).

```
ϵ = 0.1;
f = 0.01;
μ = 0.1;

Ω[a_] := 1 + ϵ (3/8 a^2 + Sqrt[f^2/(4 a^2) - μ^2])
a[Ω_] = InverseFunction[Ω][Ω];
Plot[a[Ω], {Ω, 1., 1.6}, AxesLabel -> {"Ω", "a"}]
```

[image: plot]